# Converting cURL call to Coldfusion (cfhttp)

Tags: curl, coldfusion

This may be pretty simple, not entirely sure.  Is there a way to take this cURL call below (it's from Big Commerce's API) and rewrite the same function using cfhttp?  I know cfhttp acts (or can act like) a form/method="post" type deal, but I'm not sure what params (or what their names should be) to use within a cfhttp tag.  Any help would be appreciated...my goal is to be able to use Coldfusion to call a list of products, at which point I can arrange/export to a list/excel/whatever, but setting up the actual call using cfhttp and converting this cURL call is what I'm stuck at.

```
curl --request GET \
 --user-agent "Your Client Name/1.0" \
 --header "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46WW91ckFQSUtleUhlcmU=" \
 https://www.example.com/api/v2/products
```

Comment: Docs are here: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttpparam.html

Answer (score 9):

Should be something along the lines of:

```
<cfhttp
    method="get"
    url="https://www.example.com/api/v2/products"
    userAgent="Your Client Name/1.0">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" value="Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46WW91ckFQSUtleUhlcmU=">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: But what about the authorization code then?  Using the above code, I get a connection error...meaning the code is close, but assuming some type of verification is off?

Comment: you could try: <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic YWRtaW46WW91ckFQSUtleUhlcmU=">. Just a shot in the dark. The Basic Authentication is the username:password in base64 format.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="#myUrl#">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic YWRtaW46WW91ckFQSUtleUhlcmU" />
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Interested in this as well